# Displaying jQuery objects in a loop to display 3 latest lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, object

I have a SharePoint list that I'm using that is being populated with a RSS Feed web-part. I'm stuck on a part where I'm needing to display some content but it's not working correctly. Below I will describe all the steps that I'm doing.

1.) Microsoft Flow RSS to SharePoint list is working OK.

[image]

2.) Here is my JS code which is working OK. This is the roadmap.js file.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $pnp.setup({
  baseUrl: "https://fh126cloud.sharepoint.com/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training"
 });

 $pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("O365RoadMap").items.get().then(function(z){
  console.log(z);
  var result = z.results.map(a => ({
   Title: `${a.Title}`,
   Description: `${a.Description}`,
   Link: `${a.Link}`
   })
  );
  console.log(result);

  roadMapDisplay(result);
 })

function roadMapDisplay(result) {
 var head = "<h1>" + result.Title + "</h1><br/>";
 var desc = "<p>" + result.Description + "</p><br/>"; 
 var link = "<a src='${result.Link}'>" + result.Link + "</a><br/>";
 $(".Title").append(head + desc + link);
}
   });
```

3.) It's pulling the data into objects which is what I need. It's pulling the "Title", "Description" and "Link" from both objects correctly which is OK.

[image]

4.) Here is the result from one of the objects inside the dev console on chrome. This portion is pulling both objects OK.

[image]

5.) Here is my HTML portion, this part is where I'm having trouble. I can't seem to display the results from "Title" "Description" and "Link". I'm wanting to only display the latest three objects within the SharePoint list. I need to create a loop that loops the objects with a max of three results `[0][1][2]`.

6.) Here is the roadmap.txt file that the .js file is being referenced from.

```html
<div class="Title"></div>
 
<script src="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/SiteAssets/roadmap.js?v=1"></script>
```

Everything works ok until the HTML part (roadmap.txt), I just need to create a loop to grab the Title, Description, and Link objects and display them.

Here is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Comment: In the commented function your selector is: `$("Title")`. Which would select `<Title></Title>` elements, if there were any. But, most likely, you want to use `$(".Title").append(/* stuff */)` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Andrei, I went ahead and corrected that!

Comment: Uncomment the `roadMapDisplay` function, It should work. If it doesn't, update with any errors you're getting. Remember your question needs to be about a specific problem, not about getting some job done according to some requirements. Or, to make it clearer: nobody's here to write code for you. We're here to help you write code for yourself. A [mcve] greatly improves your chances at getting an answer, as it's easier for most to understand what your code does.

Comment: Hi Andrei, I went ahead and uncommented the function and it's still not displaying using the "Title" div - It's not showing any results from "Title" "Description" and "Link" objects.

Comment: Without knowing what's inside `roadmap.js` nobody can help you. Please update your question to include the minimal amount of code to reproduce your issue.

Comment: It's the Javascript portion posted above, I do apologize. I went ahead and added the filename.

Comment: Could you place the results of your request in a variable? It returns 404 for me. You seem to be getting the results just fine but have trouble with the jQuery. So let's just place the results in a variable and see the actual error, if any.

Comment: When I do "Console.log(results)", it comes back as results not defined, even tho it is.

Comment: Everything works ok until the HTML part (roadmap.txt), I just need to create a loop to grab the Title, Description, and Link objects and display them.